# how to use simple html dom get a div inner text

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; color: #404040;">innertext</div>
```

Jow can I access innertext of divs not having `class` or `id` but `span` using simple html dom php parser? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that English isn't your first language, but can I ask what you mean by "a style for its feather," I'm mystified...

Comment: Right, delete the wrong word.

Comment: @cj333 are theose style uique to whatever is on the DOM among `<div>`

Comment: hard to answer given the snippet you posted. is the div INSIDE something that CAN be selected?

Comment: @rdamborsky, @kjy112, @rdamborsky, The parent div's id and class is changeable. If DOM can not do. maybe need use php regular-expression.

Comment: You _need_ an ID or class, otherwise how do you expect to pick the `<div>` out from the others?

Comment: Read documentation here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the styles are consistent, then you can loop over all divs in the document and filter them by style.

```
var divs = document.getElementsById("div");

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var div = divs[i];

    // skip the current div if its styles are wrong
    if (div.style.cssFloat !== "left"
     || div.style.marginTop !== "10px"
     || div.style.fontFamily !== "Verdana"
     || div.style.fontSize !== "13px"
     || div.style.color !== "#404040") continue;

    var text = div.innerText || div.textContent;

    // do something with text
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the content of `style` tag if no `id` or `class` is given there like:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mysite.com/');
foreach($html->find('div[style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; color: #404040;"]') as $e)
echo $e->innertext;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to match some of their parents (which have `class` or `id` set), then traverse the DOM to the child you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. I depends on `simple_html_dom` too much, Ben Blank give me a good way. 
And I also tried php regular-expression to match the div by myself.

```
preg_match_all('/<div.*(style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; color: #404040;").*>([\d\D]*)<\/div>/iU',$html,$match);
print_r($match);
```