# if condition not running even when the condition satisfies

Tags: javascript, html

only the else statement in main.js statement where it reads scores-=1 runs and the if condition doesnt even when the condition satisfies. even after clicking on the right option my scores value doesnt increase by 1 instead it always decreasesby 1 which means it only satisfies the else statement

index.html

```
<div class="buttons">

<button id="button0"><span id="option0"></span></button>  
<button id="button1"><span id="option1"></span></button>  
<button id="button2"><span id="option2"></span></button>  
<button id="button3"><span id="option3"></span></button>  
 </div>
```

main.js

```
  var questions =[{

   question:'abcbcb',
  options:['a','b','c','d'],
  answer:'b' 
 },   { 
  question:"capital of india",
   options:['delhi','mum','pune','kol'],
   answer:'delhi'

 }]
 var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (questions.length));
 var scores = 0;


 function gameplay(){
var quesn = document.getElementById('question');
quesn.innerHTML =questions[x].question;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
var opt = document.getElementById('option'+i);
opt.innerHTML = questions[x].options[i];
var score = document.getElementById('scores');
score.innerHTML = scores;
}

}

 gameplay();

 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
     var y = document.getElementById('button'+i);
     var z = document.getElementById('option'+i);
     y.onclick = function(){
        if((z.innerHTML) ==(questions[x].answer)){
            scores +=1;
        }
        else{
            scores -=1;
        }
        x=Math.floor(Math.random() * (questions.length));
         gameplay();
     }
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get innertext of a DIV using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903993/how-to-get-innertext-of-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: I tried it with document.getElementbyid('option0').text()

Comment: Okay, `getElementbyid` doesn’t exist: check the spelling. `text` is a jQuery method, not a native DOM method.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: sorry for the typing error. but document.getElementbyId ('button0').innerText also doesnt work

Comment: the console doesnt show any errors

Comment: `getElementbyId` is still misspelled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use simple html dom get a div inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284118/how-to-use-simple-html-dom-get-a-div-inner-text)

Comment: i have edited my question . please look into it

Answer (score 2):

For pure Javascript, use the `innerHTML` property.

For your example, use the following:

```
var spanVal = document.getElementById("option0").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

var x = document.getElementById("option0").innerHTML;

console.log(x)

That is how you can attain the value, ".innerText" would also work.

(btw you labeled this as a question in java,  this is javascript.  Very different.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**[WORKING SAMPLE](https://codepen.io/jromemcshev/pen/qxMOzE)**

Replace this

```
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
     var y = document.getElementById('button'+i);
     var z = document.getElementById('option'+i);
     y.onclick = function(){
        if((z.innerHTML) ==(questions[x].answer)){
            scores +=1;
        }
        else{
            scores -=1;
        }
        x=Math.floor(Math.random() * (questions.length));
         gameplay();
     }
   }
```

With this

```
 function answer(ans)
 {
var myAnswer = document.getElementById('option'+ans);
if(myAnswer.innerHTML == (questions[x].answer))
{
    scores += 1;
}
else{
    scores -= 1;
}
x=Math.floor(Math.random() * (questions.length));
     gameplay();

console.log(ans);
}
```

Then this

```
 <p id="question"></p> 
  <div class="buttons">
 <button id="button0"><span id="option0"></span></button>  
 <button id="button1"><span id="option1"></span></button>  
 <button id="button2"><span id="option2"></span></button>  
 <button id="button3"><span id="option3"></span></button>  
 </div>
 <p id = 'scores'></p>
```

With this

```
    <p id="question"></p> 
<div class="buttons">
<button id="button0" onclick ="answer('0')"><span id="option0"></span></button>  
<button id="button1" onclick ="answer('1')"><span id="option1"></span></button>  
<button id="button2" onclick ="answer('2')"><span id="option2"></span></button>  
<button id="button3" onclick ="answer('3')"><span id="option3"></span></button>  
</div>
<p id = 'scores'></p>
```

Comment: edited it! sorry shud have done it earlier! please look into it

Comment: @rohan i think this is still incomplete, where is your `question` tag that you specified in your javascript function ?

Comment: well, i didnt mention it my question as that was not important and to avoid too much of code.

Comment: @rohan i cant identify your error because in your function you specify some elements that's not in your `document`, also it throws errors related to the elements that's not specified. [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpk47b92/10/)

Comment: there is <p id="question"></p> ,i am not mentioning it to avoid ambiguity. everything else is working apart from if statement.

Comment: let me simplify it! i want to store the  text value  written inside a button on clicking it .how to do it from my code?

Comment: cant find what you edited. each line seems exactly similar to mine .. can you please write the particular lines of edited code ?thanks

Comment: @rohan please check it again

Comment: yeah this will work but can u tell me wat was the problem in my code? thanks btw

Comment: @rohan on your `for loop` it always throws `i` value as `4` thats the error

Comment: how? can u elaborate it?

Comment: @rohan at the last line of your `for` loop try `console.log(i)` you will see it always throws `4`

Comment: yeah i did try it initially but why it is doing so , i cannot understand that! i know i am being silly and repetitive ,sorry for that

Comment: @rohan i dont have exact idea either. but i think your `loop` is finishing all of the iteration first before proceeding to your code

Comment: @rohan no worries