# How to get text from <p> tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I want to change the content of the p tag after three seconds using `setInterval()` method. Then after three seconds I want to change the content inside of the `p` tag, with a new interval of 5 seconds. This is my code snippet:

**background.js**

```js
var notify;
var word=function(){
    $.get("http://localhost/chrome-notification/dosya.php", function (data) {
        $('#container').html(data);
    });
};

setInterval(word,3000);

setInterval(function(){
    $.get("http://localhost/chrome-notification/", function (response) {
      notify=$(response).getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
    });
},5000);
```

**index.html**

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    <title>Vocabulary</title>
</head>

<body>

<p id="container">

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use simple html dom get a div inner text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284118/how-to-use-simple-html-dom-get-a-div-inner-text)

Comment: What is _not working_ ?

Comment: @RayonDabre notify variable does not get the value of p tag

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in pure js.

```
var text = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can simply do `$(response).find('p:eq(0)').html()`

I've written some more examples here https://jsbin.com/modaxayaki/edit?html,js,console

Comment: when i do alert(notify), get undefined message.

Comment: Try debugging your application, does `alert($(response).find('p').size())` give you more than one as a result? If so, the `p` tags are found in the response.

Comment: p tag is not getting value.Because alert($(response).find('p').size()) return 0

Comment: Which means your `response` does not contain any `p` tags.

Comment: response is return a html page content

Comment: Could you try to paste here `console.log(response)` please?

Comment: console.log(response) output
<pre>                                                                                                                                      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    <title>Vocabulary</title>
</head>

<body>

<p id="container" style="color: #db9338">

</p>

</body>
</html>
</pre>

Comment: @HarunKeleşoğlu check this jsbin https://jsbin.com/modaxayaki/edit?html,js,console

Comment: i changed to code and added as answer.You can take a look

Answer (score -3):

If i understaned good, i would recommend adding CSS and linking it to html.
(If is that for what you need it for)

Make tag in css and customize it